# plotting in R: getting lines instead of points

Tags: r, plot

I have 9 points of data for 9 countries:

```
var <- structure(list(countries = structure(c(1L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("BU", "CZ", "ES", "HU", "LT", "LV", "PL", 
"SL", "UK"), class = "factor"), Eurasian.lynx = c(NA, 0, 0.063, 
0, 0.028, NA, NA, 0.0415, 0.058), Grey.wolf = c(0, 0.048, 0.11, 
0.24, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0), Brown.bear = c(0, 0.0332, NA, NA, 0.032, 
NA, NA, 0, 0), Wild.boar = c(0.076, 0.03, 0.072, 0.058, 0.089, 
0, 0, 0, 0.064), Moose = c(NA, 0.04, 0.067, 0.086, 0.087, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.078), Red.deer = c(NA, 0.033, 0.039, 0.052, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0146, 0.03), Roe.deer = c(0.025, 0.037, 0.12, 0.08, NA, 0, 
0.02, 0.00938, 0)), .Names = c("countries", "Eurasian.lynx", 
"Grey.wolf", "Brown.bear", "Wild.boar", "Moose", "Red.deer", 
"Roe.deer"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I am trying to make a species vs countries in R. Here is my code:

```
var = read.csv('variance.csv', header = T, sep = ',')
attach(var)
plot(Grey.wolf ~ countries, col = 'green',type = 'p', pch = 19, cex = 2.5,    ylab='',xlab='')
```

But instead of points I get these ugly lines: [image]
What am I doing wrong?
 Thank you!

Comment: Screenshot are useless. Use `dput()` to provide data.

Comment: Thank you! Will do next time.

Comment: No, do it now, please

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how to use this dput() thing. Also, I found the answer to my question, see below. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `dput(var)`, copy and paste the output. And I strongly discourage you to use `attach`.

Comment: Done! Just edited the post. Thank you for your peer pressure :)

Comment: Just learn how to ask a question and don't argue.

Comment: Could you please be polite? Thank you. FYI, everybody does mistakes.

Comment: And I show you how to avoid these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just found how to do it: `xyplot(Grey.wolf ~ countries,  type='p', col = 'green', pch = 19, cex = 2.3, xlab = '', ylab = '')`